# ReferenceError: inject is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mocking, jasmine

When I run the SpecRunner HTML file I get this error.

Looking around, this is due to `angular-mocks.js` not being referenced.  In my case it is being referenced.

SpecRunner.html:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/jasmine-1.3.1/jasmine.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-1.3.1/jasmine.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-1.3.1/jasmine-html.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular-mocks.js"></script>

  <!-- include source files here... -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../main/static/js/controllers/norm-definitions-controller.js"></script>
```

When the tests are run, I get this exception: `ReferenceError: inject is not defined`

I can see that `angular-mocks.js` is referenced and it's not a caching issue as I can see it using Firebug.

Looking in `angular-mocks.js` I can see the full reference `angular.mock.inject = function() { ... }`, I've tried this as a reference too, and get the exception `ReferenceError: angular is not defined`.

Comment: Make sure you don't have script dependences.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You still need `angular.js` lib. I didn't saw it among your scripts. It should be before `angular-mock.js`.

Answer (score 1):

For the errors which come while adding karma and jasmine to testing your project, make sure that

- your angular.js and angular-mocks js files both have same versions.
- the jasmine version is compatible with angularjs version, refer to jasmine official site to make sure there is no syntax error.
- refer to test formation on angular js official site to follow unit testing methodologies.

The above steps help avoid most of the common errors.